# Concatenation issues with in-built functions

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-task

Can someone please explain me why it returns only two records instead of three? I want the same result when I hard-code the delimiter as well as use the in-built SQL function(s).

```
SELECT 'HASH(IFNULL(COST_CENTER, '''') || IFNULL(MATCH_DATE, ''''))::bigint'
UNION 
SELECT CONCAT('HASH(', CONCAT_WS(' || ', 'IFNULL(COST_CENTER, '''')', 'IFNULL(MATCH_DATE, '''')' ), ')::bigint')
UNION 
SELECT CONCAT('HASH(', CONCAT_WS('||', ' IFNULL(COST_CENTER, '''') ', ' IFNULL(MATCH_DATE, '''') ' ), ')::bigint')
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first 2 lines are the same, so when you use a UNION, it dedupes them down to a single record.  If you want all three lines, use a `UNION ALL` instead.

Comment: Such a silly thing, how did I miss it? :-o Thanks Mike :-)